Add label item to legend similar to geom_label_repel()
I have a plot of species richness that has nine lines. I have labelled each line at the end using geom_label_repel() with the appropriate quadrate number. I want to add in my legend a similar black label box with a number 1 or a hash (#) in it with 'Quadrat Number' written next to it.
This is my current plot:

This an edited version in powerpoint that id like the legend to look like:

Subset of data:
data for plot (index):
structure(c("function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, ", 
"    verbose = getOption(\"verbose\"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) ", 
"{", "    fileExt <- function(x) {", "        db <- grepl(\"\\\\.[^.]+\\\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$\", x)", 
"        ans <- sub(\".*\\\\.\", \"\", x)"), dim = c(6L, 1L), dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

labels for plot (labels_df):
structure(list(Quadrat = structure(1:9, levels = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2024L, 
2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L, 2024L), ID = c("1_24", 
"2_24", "3_24", "4_24", "5_24", "6_24", "7_24", "8_24", "9_24"
), Source = c("Beaver", "Beaver", "Beaver", "Beaver", "Beaver", 
"Beaver", "SSSI", "SSSI", "SSSI"), specNum = c(20L, 21L, 19L, 
6L, 2L, 8L, 15L, 29L, 16L), simpson = c(0.95, 0.952380952380952, 
0.947368421052632, 0.833333333333333, 0.5, 0.875, 0.933333333333333, 
0.96551724137931, 0.9375), shannon = c(2.99573227355399, 3.04452243772342, 
2.94443897916644, 1.79175946922805, 0.693147180559945, 2.07944154167984, 
2.70805020110221, 3.36729582998647, 2.77258872223978), H = c(2.99573227355399, 
3.04452243772342, 2.94443897916644, 1.79175946922805, 0.693147180559945, 
2.07944154167984, 2.70805020110221, 3.36729582998647, 2.77258872223978
), fisher = c(4294967306, 4294967306.5, 4294967305.5, 1073741869.66667, 
268435505.000009, 2147483652, 4294967303.5, 4294967310.5, 4294967304
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

Code for plot
library(ggplot2)            # for plottin graphs
library(ggrepel)            # for geom_label_repel()
library(pals)               # for lines colour scale

specPlot <- ggplot(index, aes(x=Year, y=specNum, group=Quadrat, color=Quadrat, linetype=Source)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x='Year', y='Species Richness') +
  scale_colour_manual(values = unname(kovesi.isoluminant_cgo_70_c39(n=9)), guide = "none") +
  scale_linetype_manual(name = NULL, values = c('Beaver' = 'solid', 'SSSI' = 'dashed')) +
  geom_label_repel(data=labels_df,aes(label=Quadrat),
                   direction='y',
                   segment.colour='black',
                   xlim=c(2024,2025),
                   na.rm = TRUE,
                   max.overlaps=100,
                   show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position='top',
        legend.direction = 'horizontal',
        text = element_text(size = 14, family = 'Calibri Light')) +
  coord_cartesian(clip='off')


Here is one option to achieve your desired result which fakes a legend for the "label" by mapping on the alpha aes and setting show.legend=TRUE. However, this requires some additional tweaking via the override.aes argument to get your desired symbol.
Unfortunately this will display the label in the linetype legend too and the only option I have found to get rid of this was to use the override.aes argument a second time.
library(ggplot2) # for plottin graphs
library(ggrepel) # for geom_label_repel()
library(pals) # for lines colour scale

set.seed(123)

ggplot(index, aes(x = Year, y = specNum, color = Quadrat)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Source, group = Quadrat)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Species Richness") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = unname(kovesi.isoluminant_cgo_70_c39(n = 9)), guide = "none") +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    name = NULL, values = c("Beaver" = "solid", "SSSI" = "dashed")
  ) +
  scale_alpha_manual(
    name = NULL, values = 1
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = subset(index, Year >= max(Year)),
    aes(
      label = Quadrat,
      alpha = "Quadrat Number"
    ),
    direction = "y",
    segment.colour = "black",
    xlim = c(2024, 2025),
    na.rm = TRUE,
    max.overlaps = 100
  ) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.direction = "horizontal",
    #text = element_text(size = 14, family = "Calibri Light")
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  guides(
    alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "#")),
    linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "", fill = NA, size = 0))
  )
#> `geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
#> ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?



thankyou. Is there a way so the Quadrat Number element is to the right of the beaver and SSSI legend items?

Sure. ggplot2 defaults to some kind of  "magic" algorithm for the order. But you can set the order using guide_legend(..., order = XX), e.g. set order = 1 for the linetype legend and order = 2 for the alpha legend.
